# Lua significant figures

Tags: lua, numbers, number-formatting, significant-digits

I'm trying to make a function that rounds a number up to a certain number of significant figures given by the user, for example if the user gives me the number

> 234.235534 with 5 significant numbers, the function should return 234.24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`[fs]?printf`'s `%g`](https://devdocs.io/c/io/fprintf) modifier.

> converts floating-point number to decimal or decimal exponent notation
>   depending on the value and the precision.

where, the *precision* is defined by:

> `.` followed by integer number or `*`, or neither that specifies
>   precision of the conversion. In the case when `*` is used, the
>   precision is specified by an additional argument of type `int`. If the
>   value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. If neither a number
>   nor `*` is used, the precision is taken as zero.

So, you want:

```
> return ("%.5g"):format(234.235534)
234.24
> return  ("%.6g"):format(x)
234.236
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a programmer, but I came up with this for my own use after I was disappointed by other rounding functions people recommended in lua.  This should do what you asked.

```
function sigFig(num,figures)
    local x=figures - math.ceil(math.log10(math.abs(num)))
    return(math.floor(num*10^x+0.5)/10^x)
end
```

now in terms of significant digits, it won't add additional zeros to a number to signify precision. For example:

`sigFig(234.235534,5)` will yield `234.24`

`sigFig(234.0000001,6)` will yield `234.0`, not 234.000